# Unable to access data using pandas composite index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to organise data using a pandas dataframe.

Given the structure of the data it seems logical to use a composite index; 'league_id' and 'fixture_id'. I believe I have implemented this according to the examples in the docs, however I am unable to access the data using the index.

My code can be found here; 
https://repl.it/repls/OldCorruptRadius

** I am very new to Pandas and programming in general, so any advice would be much appreciated! Thanks! **

Comment: Please give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by coping a version of your data and code here in the question instead of linking. Links can die over time and the answers won't benefit anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

For multi-indexing, you would need to use the pandas `MutliIndex` API, which brings its own learning curve; thus, I would not recommend it for beginners. Link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

The way that I use multi-indexing is only to display a final product to others (i.e. making it easy/pretty to view). Before the multi-indexing, you filter the `fixture_id` and `league_id` as columns first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(fixture, columns=features)
df[(df['fixture_id'] == 592) & (df['league_id'] == 524)]
```

This way, you are still technically targeting the indexes if you would have gone through with multi-indexing the two columns.

If you have to use multi-indexing, try the transform feature of a pandas DataFrame. This turns the indexes into columns and vise-versa. For example, you can do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(fixture, columns=features).set_index(['league_id', 'fixture_id'])
df.T[524][592].loc['event_date'] # gets you the row of `event_dates`
df.T[524][592].loc['event_date'].iloc[0] # gets you the first instance of event_dates
```